# Error loading images in Signed Jar, JNLP Application

Tags: java, swing, jnlp

I am developing JNLP Application and using maven-webstart plugin to create JNLP. When running the application in my local, it works correctly but when I run in Tomcat Server using jnlp, it does not load images and also does not give any exception.

I am loading images as below

```
new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/icons/save.png"))
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: How is the path to the images inside your JAR?

Comment: myApplication.jar!/icons/save.png is the path. Inside jar you will directly see the image in /icons/save.png

Comment: Then, everything is correct. Can you check whether you get a stream using 'getClass().getResourceAsStream()' ? If the result is 'null', the path is wrong. If you get a stream, the rest of your code seems to be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Where are your icons located? How do you run a jnlp application inside tomcat? Assuming you don't have a lot of images, you can package them inside one of your packages. Just create a package called com.yourproject.resources and dump some images there. Then the way to access them would be:
//define it in some class

```
public URL obtainImageResource ( String nameOfResource )
    {
        return getClass().getResource( "/com/yourproject/resources/" + nameOfResource );
    }
```

Do get them with a URL.
Then to create the stuff you need:

```
BufferedImage yourImage = ImageIO.read( yourclaass.obtainImageResource( "yourimagepng.png" ).openStream() );
```

Note some things: In my setup you need to package your images into your jar.

Comment: I packaged images in main jar file. Your solution is the same with mine. I mean with tomcat that I create a static html page and linked jnlp file. When user clicks the link, automatically download and run jnlp application.

Comment: why use a tomcat servlet container then? Try with plain old apache if you need it only to host a static html page and linked jnlp page, you need only a normal web server, not a servlet container.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say without more information. You might use `jar -tf` to see if the images are in the JAR file. In the meantime, here's a working JWS [application](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/googleolympiad) that loads images, for reference.

Comment: Thanks for sample application. My images are located in jar file. I also checked it.

Comment: Can you launch the jnlp if it's on a different server, other than tomcat? Is the server's [mime type](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/faq.html#223) set correctly?